# Как запустить фрагмент при нажатии на уведомление

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

ЗДравствуйте, мне необходимо реализовать открытие активности с определенным фрагментом.

Как это реализовать?

Само собой в сервисе это не работает:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ExamFragment.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);
```

Но зато работает этот код, он запускает активность и старый фрагмент(который был последний открыт):`

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);
```

Как при нажатии на уведомление открывать активность с нужным фрагментом?

Answer (score 2):

Невозможно отобразить фрагмент без активити.

Вам надо запустить активити так, чтобы она знала что ей нужно отобразить строго определённый фрагмент.

Для этого поместите что-нибудь в интенет запуска активити, в активити вытащите это и в зависимости от него отображайте требуемый фрагмент

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityFragments.class);
        intent.putExtra("ExamFragment","ExamFragment");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);


Это будет отоправка интента в активность?

Comment: @MartinezToni, да. После этого будет либо onCreate вызван либо onNewIntent

Comment: Но когда я его достаю в активности, value = null, почему? 
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String value = inente.getStringExtra("ExamFragment");

Comment: @MartinezToni, вы это в каком методе делаете? В onNewIntent должно работать